# cannot merge an entity that has been removed : actgp

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

This code is giving an error "Cannot merge an entity that has been removed"
InvoiceDetail has a list of ActGps

this code is a snippet code of a function in invoice detail
it is trying to delete an entity where it not must be deleted

```
 // initialize needed fields

List<ActGP> oldActGPs = new ArrayList<>();
if (actGPs != null && !actGPs.isEmpty())
    oldActGPs.addAll(actGPs);
actGPs = new ArrayList<>();

   // get actGP (if exists in visit and not canceled)
            // if exist --> reset fields (reset prices)
            // else --> create new ActGP
            actGP = actGPs.stream().filter(agp -> agp.getVGPId() == vgp.getId()).findAny().orElse(null);

            if (actGP == null) {
                // case of adding a new act from departments OR add new GP in visit
                actGP = createNewActGP(vgp, currAct);

            } else {
                // actGP exists 
                // OR case when reCompute method called
                actGP.resetPriceFields();
                if (!oldActGPs.isEmpty())
                    oldActGPs.remove(actGP); // after the for loop we will have in oldActGPs the actGP for canceled GPs
                actGP.setGptId(0);
            }

  if (!oldActGPs.isEmpty()) {
       for (ActGP a : oldActGPs) {
         a.setInvoiceDetail(null); // removed from list ==> should be deleted from DB
        }
     }
```

Comment: There is neither an entitymanager nor a call to merge visible in the given code.

Comment: The logic you've posted doesn't make sense to me. Why stream and filter over actGPs when you've just created a new empty list for it?